# How to extract the coefficients from a linear model without repeating my code in R?

Tags: r, regression, montecarlo

I am using a Montecarlo simulation for predicting mpg in the mtcars data. I want to extract the coefficients of all the variables in the dataframe to compute how many times each car has lower mpg than the other car. For example how many times Toyota Corona has less predicted mpg than Datsun 710. This is my initial code using only two independent variables. I want to expand this selection to use all the variables in the data frame without manually have to include all the variables in the data frame.
Is there any way I can do this?

```
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(data.table, fixest, stargazer, dplyr, magrittr)

df <- mtcars
fit <- lm(mpg~cyl + hp, data = df)
fit$coefficients[1]

beta_0 = fit$coefficients[1] # Intercept 
beta_1 = fit$coefficients[2] # Slope
beta_2 = fit$coefficients[3]
set.seed(1)  # Seed
n = 1000     # Sample size
M = 500      # Number of experiments/iterations


estimates_DT <- do.call("rbind",lapply(1:M, function(i) {
  # Generate data
  U_i = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 2) # Error
  X_i_1 = rnorm(n, mean = 5, sd = 5) # First independent variable
  X_i_2 = rnorm(n, mean = 5, sd = 5) #Second ndependent variable
  Y_i = beta_0 + beta_1*X_i_1 + beta_2*X_i_2 + U_i  # Dependent variable
  
  # Formulate data.table
  data_i = data.table(Y = Y_i, X1 = X_i_1, X2 = X_i_2)
  
  # Run regressions
  ols_i <- fixest::feols(data = data_i, Y ~ X1 + X2)  
  ols_i$coefficients
}))

estimates_DT <- setNames(data.table(estimates_DT),c("beta_0","beta_1","beta_2"))

compareCarEstimations <- function(carname1="Mazda RX4",carname2="Datsun 710") {
  car1data <- mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == carname1,c("cyl","hp")]
  car2data <- mtcars[rownames(mtcars) == carname2,c("cyl","hp")]
  
  predsCar1 <- estimates_DT[["beta_0"]] + car1data$cyl*estimates_DT[["beta_1"]]+car1data$hp*estimates_DT[["beta_2"]]
  predsCar2 <- estimates_DT[["beta_0"]] + car2data$cyl*estimates_DT[["beta_1"]]+car2data$hp*estimates_DT[["beta_2"]]
  
  list(
    car1LowerCar2 = sum(predsCar1 < predsCar2),
    car2LowerCar1 = sum(predsCar1 >= predsCar2)
  )
}

compareCarEstimations("Toyota Corona", "Datsun 710")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gone all the way through your example, but here is the nugget of how to construct a set of randomized predictor variables and matrix-multiply them by the coefficient vector to get predicted values:

Setup:

```r
df <- mtcars
fit <- lm(mpg~cyl + hp, data = df)
n <- 1000
```

```r
beta <- coef(fit) ## parameter vector (includes intercept)
npar <- length(beta)
X <- matrix(rnorm(n*npar),ncol=npar)  ## includes intercept
## scale columns by the corresponding sd
## (all identical in this case)
X <- sweep(X, MARGIN=2, FUN="*", STATS=rep(5,npar))
## shift columns by the corresponding mean
## (all identical in this case)
X <- sweep(X, MARGIN=2, FUN="+", STATS=rep(5,npar))
Y0 <- X %*% beta
Y <- rnorm(n, mean=Y0, sd=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ben. This line of code throws me an error ```X <- sweep(X, MARGIN=2, FUN="*", STATS=c(2,rep(5,npar-1))) ``` This is the error message  ```Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In sweep(X, MARGIN = 2, FUN = "*", STATS = c(2, rep(5, npar - 1))) :```
  STATS is longer than the extent of 'dim(x)[MARGIN]'

Comment: I was reading the documentation trying to figure out what you did. Just a few questions. 1) The error term that I previously defined as u_i, now is inside of the X? Basically to solve my problem I need to incorporate your approach inside my ```do.call``` as a substitute for the error term, X, and Y? I appreciate your help!

Comment: oops, sorry, I misread your u_i as an intercept term. I'm going to edit a bit more. And yes, this goes where you generate each replicate of the synthetic data.