# How do I find the exact equation for a Caret model in R?

Tags: r, regression, caret

I used Caret to create a regression model of a dataset in R, and I wish to find this equation for usage in other websites (e.g. Desmos). I am unable to find info anywhere on how to do this, so if anyone has answers, that would be much appreciated! :D

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you want to extract the slope and estimated coefficients (betas) from the fitted model?

Comment: Yes! That is what I am asking! I'm very sorry if I was too vague, coding is not my area of specialty. But if there's any way of extracting slope and betas it would be very helpful! (Oh and by the way it's a Lasso model)

Comment: It's a common question, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055044/how-to-extract-the-coefficients-of-a-linear-model-and-store-in-a-variable-in-r